# Eclipse GWT com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode adds -xstartOnFirstThread to VM_ARGS on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

If my Run Configuration has com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode as the main class, Google Web Toolkit plugin adds -xstartOnFirstThread by default. The .launch file gets modified and this becomes a problem if you would like to share this file in version control with Windows users.

Is there a way to disable this vm arg being added? This does not happen if the main class is com.google.gwt.dev.GWTShell

Comment: What version of GWT are you using?

Comment: Why don't you use GWT run configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Plugin for Eclipse (and GWT Designer) adds in -XstartOnFirstThread to your launch config in some cases if you are running on MacOs.  It is a hack for problems running in a Mac JVM for the pre GWT 2.0 hosted mode.

The symptoms you're describing sound like the opposite of what I'd expect.  The flag should be added for GWTShell, but not for DevMode.  If your version of the plugin is up to date and you are using GWT 2.0+ the flag shouldn't be added. I'm not sure how they are getting in there in the first place, but you can safely scrub the argument out of your .launch files sith some script like

```
find '*.launch' | sed -i s/-XstartOnFirstThread//
```

and re-check them in.  GPE will put the flag back on for Mac users behind the scenes.

Comment: I am using GWT 2.3. Although I could modify each file to remove the flag, Eclipse plugin will automatically put it back in every single time, thus muddying up my SVN status with all these modified launchers.

Comment: So, are you launching GwtShell or DevMode as your entry point?  Does switching to the other help? (You will need a war/ directory setup for DevMode)